# Prove that the inverse of $R^{-1}$ is $R$. That is, $(R^{-1})^{-1}$ = $R$.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

The inverse of $R^{-1}$ is $R$. That is,  $(R^{-1})^{-1}$ = $R$. I have to prove that this is true. In this case, R is a relation from the set A to the set B.

I know that $R = \{(x,y)\ \in \ A \times B  \ | \ (x,y)\ \in \ R\}$. I also know that $R^{-1} = \{(y,x)\ \in \ B \times A  \ | \ (x,y)\ \in \ R\}$. Since the two are supposed to be equal, I have to show that $R^{-1} \subseteq R$ and $R \subseteq R^{-1}$ to prove equality. I just don't know how to go about doing so.

Comment: Take an arbitrary element in one set, show it is in the other set, and vice versa.

Comment: @RushabhMehta yeah I thought that was how I had to do it, I just didn't exactly know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the two are equal. You're showing taking the inverse of the inverse relation gives you the original relation.

$$(R^{-1})^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in A \times B \mid (y,x) \in R^{-1}\}$$
$$ = \{(x,y)\in A \times B \mid (x,y) \in R\} \checkmark$$

Comment: To show equivalence though, you have to show that the two are subsets of each other.

Comment: For the two parts prior to this part of the question, I had to show that (1) the domain of $R^{-1}$ is the range of $R$, and (2) that the range of $R^{-1}$ is the domain of $R$. I did so using the "subset and equivalence method".

Comment: @Claire The two relations are not necessarily equal. A could be different from B.